# suggestions for a html designer for the php eclipse package

Tags: php

I'm using an eclipse installation I downloaded mainly for PHP development. Now I want to add a HTML visual desiger. Any suggestions? I'm an eclipse newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a WYSIWYG editor? I've never been a fan of those since most create some pretty ugly code but I found this one for eclipse: http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html

I have not tried it yet so I don't know if it will suffice for your needs.